# What is the mode of the Dirichlet distribution when some $\alpha_i < 1$

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, dirichlet-distribution

Suppose $X \sim \mathcal D(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_p)$, and suppose $\alpha_i < 1$ for some $\alpha_i$. In this case, the density is unbounded, and so no proper "mode" can exist.

On the other hand, I think it is still reasonable to ask what, in some sense, the mode is. For example, suppose $X \sim \mathcal D(.3, .7)$ (so, a beta distribution). The density is unbounded but, in some sense, the mode is $(0, 1)$ because neighborhoods of $1$ get more mass than neighborhoods of $0$. Similarly, the mode of $X \sim \mathcal D(\epsilon, 200, 300)$ should essentially be $\hat X = (0, 2/5, 3/5)$.

Is there a way to make this idea precise? My thinking is that, if one has some components for which $\alpha_i < 1$, we can simply throw them away and consider the Dirichlet distribution conditioned on $X_i = 0$. In that case, due to the aggregation property of the Dirichlet, one would set the first component $\hat X_1 = 0$ and then choose $(\hat X_2, \hat X_3)$ to be the mode of a $\mathcal D(200, 300)$ distribution, which works out to $(199/498, 299 / 498)$.

Comment: Perhaps the better question is to ask why the mode is only defined for $a_i>1\forall i\in I$

Comment: @user777 Maybe that is a fine question to ask, but I'm interested in implementing an algorithm which depends on what the answer to the question I asked is. :P